# Putting duplicate phrases in the headings of pages

Tags: seo, heading

If I have a local business that repairs only HP computers for example, and I write lots of good informative pages about all the different things that can be repaired on HP computers such as motherboards, screens and keyboards, should I make the `h1` headings of my pages:

- Motherboard repair for HP computers
- Screen repair for HP computers
- Keyboard repair for HP computers

or

- Motherboard repair
- Screen repair
- Keyboard repair

?

What different does it make to search engines?  If the first option is a bad idea, how should I make sure to communicate to search engines that my business specializes in HP computers?

Answer (score 2):

Keep it natural and serve best value for your audience.

If you only repair HP computers, then this should be made pretty obvious when visitors land on your website. Page titles should contain this so users of search engines are aware of this prior to clicking through to your website. There oughtn't be a need for this message to be replicated through page's headers.

Contrary to the other answer, meta description bears no reflection on search engine rankings and ought to be used to *sell* that page in the event a search engine displays your defined *meta description* in the search results for your site's listings. The *meta keywords* isn't even worth worrying about, there isn't anything of any significance or value that uses this tag any more.

Keeping your header tags to simple and clear descriptions of what that page is about such as 'Motherboard repairs' and 'Keyboard repairs' is natural, visitors will understand this and search engines will understand it. It is relevant providing that section contains content relating to the header. Only use one `h1` tag on the page and you can also use sub sections of `h2` or `h3` where necessary to break the page architecture down further still.

The header tags on their own don't hold a particularly great amount of weight for page performance in organic search so be sure to serve great content along with well structured and relevant headings, sub headings, imagery and page titles.

Answer (score 1):

Sure  may not affect search rankings but the Description sometimes appears in search results so I'd put it there.  I'd also look at setting up your locality in Webmaster Tools. As to the other tags why not adopt a mixed approach:

```
<meta name="Description" content="XXX Ltd repairs motherboard for HP computers in Philadelphia" />
<meta name="keywords" content="hp motherboard repair"/>

 <title>Hewlett Packard Motherboard Repair in Philadelphia</title>
<h1>HP Motherboard Repair</h1>
<p>XXX Ltd of XXXX, Philadelphia specializes in the repair of motherboards of HP computers and laptops.......</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `h1` tag should be utilized to provide an accurate description of the content on the entire page. However, this isn't the only element that search engines reference.

Personally, I weight *meta keywords and description*, as well as page titles right up there with the `h1` tag. A Google search will give you plenty of articles that argue the importance of the `h1` tag, and contradict each other regarding its relevance.

In your situation, I would recommend sticking with "Motherboard repair," "Screen repair," etc. for your primary headings. Be sure to include those specific details about HP computers in your page description, *meta keywords*, page titles, etc.

Comment: Meta tags do not affect ranking and haven't for years

Comment: Description might be adopted by the search engine and be delivered in the "results list" as supporting information. Does not effect ranking but it is useful... "usually"

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the first option (with *HP computers*), you tell to search engines your business is really related to *HP computers*, especially if you put these keywords in `h1` of all your webpages. Problem is if one day, you decide to repair *Asus or Acer computers*, you will be obliged to change all `h1` tags. With this option, you give more weight to *HP computers* keywords.

If you choose the second option (without *HP computers*), you tell to search engines your business is really related to *computers repair*. You give more weight to *computers repair* keywords.

If I were you, I will choose the second option because:

- If you are be able to repair *HP computers*, you can repair *Asus or Acer computers*.
- It appears to me less spammy

Even better for your local business, you can put local keyword in `h1` tags like *Motherboard repair in Philadelphia* (assume you work in Philadelphia).

Comment: Isn't adding "in Philadelphia" to every H1 tag considered spammy by search engines?

Comment: If your webpage is about "Philadelphia", no problem.